# Apk installs on other devices, but stops responding straight after opening it

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

I'm having a problem. I'm developing an Android App and when I run it via USB Debugging on a device it runs perfectly as it should. But when I Generate an apk or send app-debug.apk to someone, the app installs fine but then it says "unfortunately, app has stopped responding" when they open it.

There's also something else. When I use the same apk on the phone that I am using for for testing using USDB debugging, the apk installs and the app runs as expected. Why can't it run on the other devices? Even through building a signed apk it still doesn't work.

Test phone is running Android 7.0 and the devices that the app is crashing on are 6.0 and 5.0.

I've also tested the apk on a device I also have that has Android 6.0, I did USB debugging on it and the app opened. I also used the same apk file on that exact phone and it worked fine! The app also worked on another phone that has android 4 which I ran the app through USB Debugging and it worked and then I installed the apk and it worked.

Why isn't the app working on other devices that I send the apk to?? I am very confused now.

Here are some screenshots:
Additional Information: I'm using Android Studio to build this app.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the code. An endless loop could cause this.

Comment: Maybe getting the actual crash report would help you solve the issue, don't you think?

Comment: Without seeing the actual crash log I can only assume this is something related to data that is retrieved from a server not being ready to use when running the apk, in some cases when debugging the time it takes to actually start the debugger or even a breakpoint will make the process to finish and the app will act as normal.

Comment: I found the problem. There were some conflicts with the design library and appcompat library. I fixed that by changing them to the same version and that seems to have fixed the problem! Thank you for pitching in.